# Effect of pseudo classes on child- and parent-elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I have a `<input>` inside a `<div>`. 
Now if I use the pseudo-class `:hover` both of the elements gets the pseudo-class.

But If i use `:focus` only the `<input>` gets that pseudo-class.
 I have read that only certain elements can have the `:focus` pseudo-class and `<div>` is not one of them.

Now I wonder if there is some other pseudo-class I can use that exist on both tags with similar behavior as `:focus`, but will appear on both tags like `:hover` does.

UPDATE:
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PuYfNPL1Ie8I8pdv5btq?p=preview)  illustrating the problem.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve here?

Comment: set `tabindex='0'` to the div and `:focus` works: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/qORLar

Comment: I want to style the outer `<div>` when the `<input>` has focus( `:focus`), but i get that that doesn't work. If the `<input>` is hovered (`:hover`), the div gets `:hover` as well. Now I would like that behavior, only with something like focus. Does that make sense?

Comment: @zvona tabindex did not work. And the codepen does not seem to work either..

Comment: @Gustav ... The codepen demo works well on chrome and firefox.

Comment: @Gustav The `tabindex` solution works in so far as it will allow the `div` to be focusable. It won't solve your issue, however, as you can't focus on more than one element at a time. Please can you provide code showing what you are trying to achieve, we may be able to come up with a solution which tackles your problem from a different angle.

Comment: Pretty sure that this isn't possible without JS/JQ. It's effectively requiring a [parent selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)...and there isn't one.

Comment: @zvona ok sorry, it does work, my problem is that the clicking occurs on the input. See the question updated with a plunker

Comment: If you are focusing in the input, the div is not focus. You can't achieve this with CSS there are not parent selector. There is an `:active` pseudoclass, but is triggered only onMouseDown, and not preserve after mouseUp

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude allright.. was there something about a parent selector in css4?

Comment: The future only time will tell. Now, you only can achieve it with javascript, something like `input.on('focus', funcBg);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you want with just `CSS`you may need a bit of jquery like:

```
$(document)
.on("focus", "input", function(){

///here what you want, in this example add a class to your div
$('div').addClass("divfocus");

})
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/fsywpe1d/)**

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, in order to be able to be focused, an element needs to be [focusable](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#focusable):

> An element is **focusable** if all of the following conditions are
>   met:
>
> - The element's [tabindex focus flag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#specially-focusable) is set.
> - The element is either [being rendered](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#being-rendered) or is a descendant of a [`canvas`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-canvas-element) element that [represents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#represents) [embedded content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedded-content-2).
> - The element is not [inert](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#inert).
> - The element is not [disabled](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html#concept-element-disabled).

In your case, the problem is the first condition. You can make the `div` focusable by setting its tabindex focus flag through a [`tabindex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-tabindex) attribute.

```css
p:focus {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<p tabindex="-1">Click me. I can be focused</p>
<p>But I can't :(</p>
```

However, there is a problem. There can only be one focused element in the document. Therefore, the `div` and the `input` can't be focused simultaneously.

In fact, you don't want to select the `div` when it is focused, you want to select it when it contains a focused element.

The Selectors Level 4 draft addresses this exact problem by creating the new `:focus-within` pseudo-class:

> [**9.4. The Generalized Input Focus Pseudo-class:
>   `:focus-within`**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-focus-within-pseudo)
>
> The ***`:focus-within`*** pseudo-class applies to elements for which
>   the [`:focus`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#focus-pseudo) pseudo class applies. Additionally, the ancestors
>   of an element that matches [`:focus-within`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#focus-within-pseudo) also match
>   [`:focus-within`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#focus-within-pseudo).

Sadly browsers don't support it yet. So meanwhile, use JS.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look for the :focus-within when it comes.